# Random guessing game - bug

Tags: c

I have a problem in this code when I enter a string, instead of integer. How do I check if the user has entred a character instead of integer? (I would like to put out a message to the user saying you should use numbers, not characters)

ALSO: if you find anything in this code I can improve, please help me! (I am new to C)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
int main () {

    int secret, answer;

    srand((unsigned)time(NULL));

    secret = rand() % 10 + 1;

    do {
        printf ("Guess a number between 1 and 10");
        scanf ("%d",&answer);
        if (secret<answer) puts ("Guess a higher value");
        else if (secret>answer) puts ("Guess a lower value");
    } while (secret!=answer);

    puts ("Congratz!");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

scanf returns the number of matches is finds. In your case it will return `1` if it readss a number. `0` if it can't read a number in:

```
if(scanf ("%d",&answer) != 1){
    puts("Please input a number");

    // Now read in the rest of stdin and throw it away.
    char ch;
    while ((ch = getchar()) != '\n' && ch != EOF);

    // Skip to the next iteration of the do while loop
    continue;
}
```

Comment: It should replace your scanf line

Comment: I figured it out. Thanks for not just making it a copy/paste, so I can learn more!!!

Comment: @user1431627 Also your if statements are backwards. You output that the number is lower if you guess too low, and you output that it is higher if you guess too high.

Comment: When I do that it only tells me to get a lower and lower number.

Comment: Yes. I did. I do not understand this actually.

Comment: But, how the heck should my code work if I have done a wrong if sentence?

Comment: Doing what I have already done works. Doing what you said I should it dose not work. I am confused.

Comment: if (secret>answer) puts ("The number is lower");
else if (secret<answer) puts ("The number is higher");

Comment: Oh, ok. Like this: if (secret<answer) puts ("Number is lower");
else if (secret>answer) puts ("Number is higher");

Comment: Thank you SO MUCH for helping me! This is one of the first days of programming in C++. Btw, this code is cross-platform?

Comment: @user1431627 AFAIK it should be cross platform, as long as it is compiled for each platform it needs to be run on. That is `C` though, not `C++`.

Comment: Cool! Would you recommend me writing in C or C++?

Answer (score 3):

Read the input as a string (`char[]` and `%s`), check all characters are (`isdigit()`) digits (possibly allowing for a `'+'` or `'-'` as first character) and use `atoi()` to convert to `int`.

Answer (score 0):

You should write a function that returns true if and only if every character in the string is a digit, and false otherwise.

```
char * in_str;
int answer;

...

sscanf("%s", in_str);

if (!is_number(in_str)) {
  printf("Please put in a number, not a letter");
} else {
  answer = atoi(in_str);
}

...
```

You need to implement the `is_number` function

Answer (score 0):

Since you can't assume that the user's input is an integer, have `scanf()` accept a string instead. Then try convert that string with `strtol()`; that will return `0` if the input was not an integer.

Answer (score 0):

Read the input as a string with `fgets` and then use `strtol` to check the input.  `strtol` contrary to `atoi` is able to do error checking.